# Access to AppSettings keys

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-config

I've some keys in my `web.config`, for example:

```
<add key="ActiveDirectoryPassword" value="Password1"/>
```

But when I call it in a class, for example:

```
string _stringTest = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectoryPassword"].ToString();
```

Always `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectoryPassword"]` is `null`. How it can be?

And, if I try to access connectionstrings section for example:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"]
```

These return the correct value.

I forget anything? I don't know what is happening.

Thanks

Comment: First things first, can you post the <appSettings> section of your web.config file. Also, how many .config files do you have? If you have more then one, then settings in different config files could be taking precedence.

Comment: What config section is the ActiveDirectoryPassword key placed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have multiple `web.config` files. One In the folder from where you are trying to access as well as in the location you are referring to. In that specific folder's web.config, it is missing keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"];,
```

This method already returns a string so there's no need to add `ToString();`

For your issue, please verify the key name, make sure the same key is available in your config file.